# Получить id из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Есть две таблицы

Таблица **press**

```
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
| id    | text     | category   |category_id   |
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
|       |          |            |              |
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Таблица **category**

```
+-------+----------+------------+
|     id|      name| img        |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  12   |  facebook|   icon.png |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  13   | football |   ball.png |
+-------+----------+------------+
```

Используя foreign key я связал  ячейку `category_id` таблицы `press` с идентификатором (`id`) другой таблицы (`category`) чтобы при удалении категории также удалялась информация из другой таблицы press (сделал это я через **phpmyadmin** поставив `on delete cascade`)

Вроде все сделал правильно ну вот никак не могу взять `id` из таблицы `category` чтобы добавить в другую таблицу `press` в категорию `category_id`

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ //при нажатии на кнопку submit
        $press_text_area =  $_POST["presstextarea"];
        $category_select = $_POST["categoryselect"];

        if(empty($press_text_area)){

            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "all fields must be field up";
            redirect_to("press.php");

            exit;
        } else if(strlen($press_text_area) < 5){ //name of category can't be 100 symbols cause in DB have a config

            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Press info should be at least 5 character's";
            redirect_to("press.php");
            exit;

        } else {
             global $db;
            //  тут мои несчастные попытки вязть идентификатор из таблицы и засунуть в переменную $post_id_from_url
             $post_id_from_url = $_GET["id"];
            //  $category_id = $db->query("SELECT 'id' FROM `category` WHERE id='$post_id_from_url'");


             $db = $db->execute("INSERT INTO `press` (text , category, category_id) VALUES('{$press_text}',
             '{$category_select}','{$post_id_from_url}'");

                if($db){
                    $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Press added succesfully";
                    redirect_to("press.php");
                }   else {
                    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Something went wrong";
                    redirect_to("press.php");
                }
        }
    }
```

Чтобы не у кого не было вопроса насчет этих `$db` переменных я покажу файл `DB.php` там все эти подключения

```
     Class Database {

         private $link;

         public function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
         }

         private function connect(){
            $config = require_once "config.php";

            $dsn = "mysql:host=".$config["host"].";dbname=".$config["db_name"].";";

            $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $config["username"], $config["password"]);

            return $this;
         }

         public function execute($sql){
            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

            return $sth->execute();
         }
         public function query($sql){
            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

            $sth->execute();

            $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($result === false){
                return [];
            }
            return $result;
         }
     }

$db = new Database();
```

Все в коде работает отлично .Только вот проблема у меня как получить идентификатор

Мои попытки

1.Как и наверху я пыталсья писать так.

```
$post_id_from_url = $_GET["id"];
            //  $category_id = $db->query("SELECT 'id' FROM `category` WHERE id='$post_id_from_url'");
```

2.Пыталсья извлечь напрямую таким образом

```
$category_id = $db->query("SELECT 'id' FROM `category`);
```

потом эту же переменную добавить как значения для ячейки `category_id`

3.пыталсья писать так

```
$category_id = $db->execute("SELECT 'id' FROM `category`);
```

И еще внизу страницы я получаю все данные из таблицы category включая id (но его не использую )и помещаю в тег select option  чтобы выбрать категорию через селект и добавить контент.

после дня серфинга

**Такой вывод**

```
$rows = $db->query("SELECT id FROM `category`");

print_r($rows);
```

Показывает ассоциативный (**всех id**) массив полученный из БД  но как добавить это как значение ?

И форма из которой должна добавлятсья информация .ВНутри **select option**-а выводитсья все информация из БД соответственно он берет имя каждой категории и идентификатор (которое мы не используем)

```
<form action="press.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>


        <label for="categoryselect">Press Category:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" id="categoryselect" name="categoryselect">

        <?php
            global $db;
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `category`");

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $name = $row["name"]; 
                $id = $row["id"];        
        ?>
            <option><?php echo $name; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>

        </select>

        <label for="presstextarea">Press Text:</label>
        <input class="pulse" type="text"  name="presstextarea" id="presstextarea" placeholder="Press Text">

        <button type="submit" name="submit">Add Press</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: У вас же `$post_id_from_url` уже хранит ИД категории. Чего вам еще надо?

Comment: Посмотрите что возвращает fetchAll, она возвращает массив. Значит и ваша функция query то же возвращает массив. Причем двумерный, там может быть несколько строк и внутри них колонки (причем по именам, потому что вы делаете FETCH_ASSOC). Итого ваш id доступен примерно как `$result=$db->query(...); $category_id=$result[0]['id'];` Правда смысл получения `select id ... where id=X` остается для меня так же загадкой, он же возвращает то же что и в условии if(X=2) X=2

Comment: @Mike спасибо конечно но ваш метод не помог __$result=$db->query(...);__внутри при обращении к БД я написал так SELECT 'id' FROM `category` не сработало. =(

Comment: что значит "не сработало". перед тем как обратится к массиву с неизвестной структурой надо распечатать этот массив и посмотреть как он на самом деле выглядит. расставьте отладочную печать внутри query, изучите, что возвращается в результате каждого из шагов, не возникает ли где ошибок.

Comment: @Mike спасибо что помогаете.Таким запросом я получил первый номер идентификатора  __$rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `category`");__  следущая строка __$category_id=$rows[0]['id'];__ я получил 12 . А теперь как ?

Comment: ну вы получили 12, это скорее всего и есть id первой попавшейся записи из таблицы category. Именно этого вы и хотели, судя по запросу. чем вас не устраивает 12 ?

Comment: Так что определитесь id какой именно записи из category вы хотите получить, по какому признаку отличить ее от всех остальных записей

Comment: @Mike  ну во первых так невозможно добавить ошибку кидает даже если возможно было и добавилось бы  12 id ко всем записям.Еще раз скажу я привязал две базы данных теперь надо чтобы при добавлении  текста в БД press также добавлясья id категории  __category__ нужный id который был выбран .Там в теге select option я выбираю же категорию потом пишу текст

Comment: Вы не привели код того select. поэтому я не знаю, что возвращается, когда пользователь в нем что то выбирает. Но вообще обычно select возвращает вам id требуемого элемента (если ваш select выглядел как то вроде `<option value='12'>название</option>` (где 12 и есть id категории). Но если это так, то возвращаемся к самому первому комментарию, который вам написали (и о чем я писал вам в своем первом коменте), вам клиент уже явно передает id требуемой категории, вам вообще не нужно обращаться к таблице category для получения еще чего либо. id у вас уже есть и вы прямо его можете использовать

Comment: @Mike добавил форму с select-om можете посмотреть.Да мне нужно просто чтобы когда из админки выбрали категории из формы и добавили текст id выбранной категории (в селекте же он выбрал категорию правильно нам также нужно взять id этой категории) попал в таблицу press в ячейку category_id чтобы когда удалялась категория также удалялась и текст написанной об этой категории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так и не смогли объяснить нам, что вы хотите, но тем не менее.

Как я вижу из формы, у вас есть `select` с именем `categoryselect`. При сабмите формы значение выбранной опции из этого селекта будет доступно в переменной `$_POST["categoryselect"]`.

Так как у вас наполнение селекта происходит **без** указания аттрибута `value` для каждого `option`, естественно вам в качестве значения `$_POST["categoryselect"]` возвращается что-то, отличное от ИД категории. Ну так измените вывод селекта, добавьте аттрибут `value`:

```
    <select class="selectpicker" id="categoryselect" name="categoryselect">
    <?php
        global $db;
        $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `category`");

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $name = $row["name"]; 
            $id = $row["id"];        
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Теперь, если вы в момент сабмита выведете `$_POST["categoryselect"]`, то он будет содержать выбранное в селекте значение, которое заинсертится в таблицу.

Надеюсь, это вам поможет. А что такое `$post_id_from_url = $_GET["id"];` так и осталось загадкой.

**Дополнение**: во-первых, вы должны понимать что сообщение `Something went wrong` ни о чем вам не говорит. Требуется использовать функции для получения текстов ошибок. В `PDO` это [`errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php). Это поможет вам понимать что **конкретно** не так.
Далее, ваш запрос на вставку:

```
INSERT INTO `press` (text , category, category_id) 
VALUES(
    '{$press_text}',
    '{$category_select}',
    '{$post_id_from_url}'
)
```

Зачем вы ввели поле (привыкайте к терминологии, ячейки оставьте в Экселе) `category`? У вас есть поле `category_id`, его достаточно, поле `category` можно удалить из таблицы `press`. Запрос на вставку должен быть таким:

```
INSERT INTO `press` (`text`, category_id) 
VALUES(
    '{$press_text}',
    '{$category_select}'
)
```

Замечания:

- Я взял в бэктики слово `text`, так как в mysql есть тип данных с таким названием. Не допускайте чтобы служебные, а тем более **зарезервированные** слова mysql пересекались с вашими запросами.
- Убрал из инсерта поле `category`. Оно не требуется в таблице `press` **совсем**.
- Обратите внимание, что если в переменной `$press_text` будет содержаться кавычка `'`, то в запросе обнаружится **синтаксическая ошибка**. Чтобы такого не было - начните **сразу** пользоваться **подготовленными выражениями**.

Comment: Спасибо большое но ваш код вывел ошибку __Something went wrong__. я новичок и не был в курсе что делает этот запрос __$_GET__  .Да я же обьяснил что я хотель. чего тут сложного user заходит в press.php выбирает категорию (через select option которые приходят из БД) потом пишет текст и жмет отправить.

Comment: Это инфа я хочу чтобы добавилось в БД вместе с ИДЕНТИФИКАТОРОМ таблицы category в ячецку category_id чтобы когда удаляешь категорию текст не оставалсья  То есть если мы выбрали категорию facebook и ввели какой то текст то в таблицу должен попасть такой текст имя выбранной категории и его идентификатор в ячейку category_id .Вот как туда добавить идентификатор соответсвующий имени категории этого я не могу .и прошу от вас.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: второй ответ тоже не рабочий выводитсья ошибка

Comment: Вы думаете что я телепат и могу угадать текст ошибки?